# Cargar datos con JSON no muestra nada

Tags: javascript, jquery

Deseo mostrar valores con JSON al recoger informacion de dos campos de texto.

Aqui los codigos:

**HTML:**

```
 <input type="text" name="valor_grados1" id="valor_grados1">Superior
 <input type="text" name="valor_grados" id="valor_grados">Novato

 <tr>
 <td>Seleccione el tipo de castigo: </td>
 <td><select onchange="obtenerAmplitud();">
 <?php
 castigos();
 ?>
 </select>
 </td>
 </tr>

 <td> Dias Simples:
      <input type="text" name="valor_amplitud1" maxlength="2" size="2" id="valor_amplitud1">
      <br>
      Dias Severos:
      <input type="text" name="valor_amplitud2" maxlength="2" size="2" id="valor_amplitud2">
```

**obtenerAmplitud()**

```
 function obtenerAmplitud() {
var gsan2= { gsancionador: $('#valor_grados1').val() }
alert(gsan2);
var gsan1= { gsancionado: $('#valor_grados').val() }
alert(gsan1);

$.post("./funciones_php_obtenerAmplitud.php", gsan2, gsan1 , function( respuesta ) 
{
    $('#valor_amplitud1').val(respuesta.simple);
    $('#valor_amplitud2').val(respuesta.severo);

}, "json" );

}
```

**obtener.php**

```
 $grado_sancionador = $_POST["gsancionador"];

  $grado_sancionado = $_POST["gsancionado"];


   //-- Obtener datos basicos de amplitud --//
  $stmt=$conexion->prepare("SELECT amplitud_dias_simple,amplitud_dias_severo FROM demeritos WHERE grado_sancionador_id=? AND grado_sancionado_id=?");
  $stmt->bind_param("ii", $grado_sancionador,$grado_sancionado);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->store_result();
  $stmt->bind_result($amplitud_simple,$amplitud_severo);
  $stmt->fetch();
   //-- ---------------------------- --//


 //-- Llenamos el JSON --//
       echo json_encode(array(
        'simple' => $amplitud_simple,
        'severo' => $amplitud_severo
           ));
      $stmt->close();
         }
```

Error de la CONSOLA

```
Uncaught TypeError: (o.dataType || "*").toLowerCase is not a function
    at Function.ajax (http://localhost/sistema/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4:12140)
    at Function.r.(anonymous function) [as post] (http://localhost/sistema/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4:14657)
    at obtenerAmplitud (http://localhost/sistema/obtenerDatosBasicos.js:7:3)
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (http://localhost/sistema/menu.php:364:61)
```

que error tiene el 7:3?

No muestra los datos

Comment: ¿Qué datos esperas obtener?, no estoy seguro del error, pero _adivinando_ podría ser que el JSON no es un objeto válido...

Comment: Sería bueno que hagas _debugging_ en la consola del navegador (F12), para que observes si está realizándose la llamada a tu servicio y lo que está retornando; no sé mucho de PHP, pero supongo que el script **obtener.php** tiene un problema y no está retornando lo que esperas.

Comment: quieres hacer una consulta en base al los datos que pones en los inputs ? y despues mostrar el resultado en otros inputs o en donde los quieres mostrar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La firma de `$.post` es:

```
<url>, <data>, <successCb>, <dataType>
```

Entonces, ¿Por qué pasas dos objetos en lugar de uno solo? La petición que realizas debe ser:

```
let data = {
  gsancionador: $('#valor_grados1').val(),
  gsancionado: $('#valor_grados').val()
};

$.post("./funciones_php_obtenerAmplitud.php", data , function( respuesta ) {
    $('#valor_amplitud1').val(respuesta.simple);
    $('#valor_amplitud2').val(respuesta.severo);
}, "json");
```

El error está relacionado con JSON; es posible que al tener un parámetro de más, se interprete el callback como `dataType` y jQuery no sea capaz de aplicar un parser correcto.

Comment: esa era mi duda de como pasar dos parametros, pues ya lo se hacer con un parametro y busque por internet y no encontraba otra forma mas que usar GET[], probare lo que me dices

Comment: Algo que falto tambien en el PHP, fue hacer echo del json

 $datos = json_encode(array(
        'simple' => $amplitud_simple,
        'severo' => $amplitud_severo

                 ));
      echo $datos;
      $stmt->close();

Comment: no hace nada todavia, utilice CONSOLE.DIR y muestra esto

Objectgsancionado: "8"gsancionador: "7"__proto__: Object

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: respuesta is not defined
    at obtenerAmplitud (obtenerDatosBasicos.js:217)

Me sale que no esta definido

usando esto console.log(JSON.stringify(respuesta));

Comment: ¿Qué has imprimido con `console.dir`? Claramente se inprime el objeto con los datos. ¿Cómo te aseguras **si tu consulta trae resultados**?

Comment: con console.dir imprime los POST de los valores, es decir gsancionador y gsancionado, cuando me meto al php directamente devuelve el array con las variables nulas, si yo le meto directo valores $g=3 $g2=3 me muestra el array json con los datos, que podra ser?.

Ahorita copie ese mismo codigo pero con un valor y sirve que podra ser?

Comment: Ahora, ese error que comentas no puede salirte, porque **respuesta SI existe y es un parámetro del callback**. En caso que `respuesta` sea undefined el error debería decirte **cannot read sancionador of undefined**.

Comment: esperare que leas los otros comentarios jejeje

Comment: Me estás diciendo que tu consulta no devuelve nada. ¿Por qué no lo dijiste desde un inicio? Empieza por resolver el asunto de tu consulta. Tienes que probar si no jamás podrás solucionar nada. Comprueba que PHP reciba los parámetros, realiza la misma consulta en tu gestor de base de datos, etc.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55330/discussion-between-victor-a-and-gustavo-garcia).

Comment: El $.post si carga los valores 
El php al meterle valores directamente genera resultados 
El problema es que no regresa nada si no le pongo valores explicitos en el post, ni siquiera da los mensajes que puse alerta dentro del php al momento de que faltara algun valor

Answer (score 1):

espero que esto te funcione.

```
<label for="clave">Clave</label>
<input type="password" name="clave" id="clave" tabindex="1" autofocus />   

<label for="nombre">valor1</label>
<input  type="text" name="valor1" id="valor1" readonly="readonly" />
```

tengo el inptu que realizará la accion que tiene como `id` calve y el input que recibirá la espuesta con el `id` valor1 mandas llamar la funcion al perder el foco el input con el `id`clave.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#clave" ).focusout(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:'obtener.php',
                type:'POST',
                dataType:'json',
                data:{clave:$('#clave').val()}
            }).done(function(respuesta){
                $("#valor1").val(respuesta.valor1);
         });
      });
    });
```

y en tu archivo php relizas la consulta y regresas los valores.

```
$clave = $_POST['clave'];

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE campo = '$clave'";
$result = $conexion->query($consulta);

$respuesta = new stdClass();
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    $fila = $result->fetch_array();
    $respuesta->nombre = $fila['valor1'];

}
echo json_encode($respuesta);
```